# Combiners , Reducers and EcoSystemProject in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reducers, combiners

What do you think of the answer for Question 4 mentioned in this [site](http://www.scribd.com/doc/234685897/CCD-410-FREE-Demo-Questions-1) will be ?

Is the answer right or wrong

**QUESTION: 4**

```
In the standard word count MapReduce algorithm, why might using a combiner reduce theoverall Job running time?

A. Because combiners perform local aggregation of word counts, thereby allowing the mappers to process input data faster.
B. Because combinersperform local aggregation of word counts, thereby reducing the number of mappers that need to run.
C. Because combiners perform local aggregation of word counts, and then transfer that data toreducers without writing the intermediate data to disk.
D. Because combiners perform local aggregation of word counts, thereby reducing the number of key-value pairs that need to be snuff let across the network to the reducers.

Answer:A
```

and

**QUESTION: 3**

```
What happens in a MapReduce job when you set the number of reducers to one?

A. A single reducer gathers and processes all the output from all the mappers. The output iswritten in as many separate files as there are mappers.
B. A single reducer gathers andprocesses all the output from all the mappers. The output iswritten to a single file in HDFS.
C. Setting the number of reducers to one creates a processing bottleneck, and since the number of reducers as specified by the programmer is used as a reference value only, the MapReduceruntime provides a default setting for the number of reducers.
D. Setting the number of reducers to one is invalid, and an exception is thrown.
Answer:A
```

From my understanding answers to the above questions

```
Question 4: D
Question 3: B
```

**UPDATE**

```
You have user profile records in your OLTP database,that you want to join with weblogs you have already ingested into HDFS.How will you obtain these user records?
Options
A. HDFS commands
B. Pig load
C. Sqoop import
D. Hive
Answer:B
```

and for updated question my answer I am doubtfull with **B** and **C**

**EDIT**

Right Answer: **Sqoop**.

Comment: +1 for pointing that out to anyone thinking about investing there...

Comment: Please see the update too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far my understanding both the answers are wrong.

I haven't worked much with the `Combiner` but everywhere I found it to be working on outputs of `Mapper`. The answer to **Question No 4** should **D**.

Again from practical experience I've found that the number of output files is always equal to the number of `Reducer`s. So the answer to the **Question No 3** should be **B**. This may not be the case when using `MultipleOutputs` but that's not common.

Finally I think Apache won't lie about MapReduce ( exceptions do occur :). The answer to the both the questions are available in their [**wiki page**](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopMapReduce#Combine). have a look.

By the way, I liked the *"100% Pass-Guaranteed or Your Money Back!!!"*  quote on the link you provided ;-)

**EDIT**
Not sure about the question in the update section since I've little knowledge on Pig & Sqoop. But certainly  the same can be achieved using Hive by creating external tables on the HDFS data & then joining.

**UPDATE**
After comments from user ***milk3422*** & the owner, I did some searching and find out that my assumption of Hive being the answer to the last question is wrong since another OLTP database is involved. The proper answer should be **C** as Sqoop is designed to transfer data between HDFS and relational databases.

Comment: +1 for both answers. A lot of people should be asking for their money back I suppose...

Comment: Yes I was also choosing the same answer.

Comment: For question 4: In map reduce, Combiners after the Mapper, before data is sent to the Reducer. Combiners are used to perform aggregation to minimize the amount of information sent to the Reducer. D is the correct answer.

For question 3: You will have as many output files as you have reducers, so answer A is incorrect. Answer B is the correct answer.

Comment: @milk3422: For update question.. why cant it be sqoop(imports data from other databases )?I have only less knowlege on other ecosystem projects

Comment: Sorry, I didn't address the third question. The best answer for that question would be C Sqoop Import. Sqoop was made to import/export data to/from HDFS and relational databases. I have used Pig quite a bit and Pig is not made for reading from HDFS.

Comment: @milk3422 : Thanks for pointing out, updated the answer. SreeVeni have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for question 4 and 3 seem correct to me. For question 4 its quite justifiable becoz while using a combiner the map output is being kept in collection n processed first then buffer is flushed when full. To justify this I will add this link : http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopMapReduce

Here it clearly states why combiner will add speed to the process.

Also I think q.3 answer is also correct becoz in general that's basic configuration followed by default. To justify that I will add another informative link: https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-7/mapreduce-types

Comment: @hunter30:  I dont think that 4 and 3 are correct answers becoz.how many reducers are we setting only 1 so all our final output goes to that 1 reducer so a single file will be the output. ie output file will be equal to no of reducers. and for question 4- combiner is done between map and reduce and combiner dont have role in speeding up the mapper process

Comment: Actually from a single reducer too you can output to multiple output files. Take a look at the hadoop API: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html

Comment: Also combiner reduces the read write operations to hdfs between map n reduce phase.some inbuilt java examples like wordcount directly use same class for combiner and reducer